# Ember.js hiding a divider with buttons, but maintaining didInsertElement functionality

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to show and hide some buttons in `Ember.js` as follows.

```
{{#view App.myView contentBinding="App.myObject"}

<div id="my_widget" class="well span3">                                                                                 
{{#if content.isConditionTrue}}                                         
  <button id="stop_button" class="btn btn-primary"> Stop </button>                                              
  <button id="start_button" class="btn btn-primary" > Start </button>
  <button id="record_button" class="btn btn-primary">Record </button>
</div>                                            
{{else}}                                            
  <div id="widget_warning_box" class="well">                                                  
    <p> No cameras are open, open a camera in Add/Remove Cameras tab. </p>                                          
  </div>
{{/if}}                                         
</div>
{{/view}}
```

and the View looks like:

```
App.myView = Ember.View.Extend({
   didInsertElement: function() {
      $record = $("#record_button")
      $start = $("#start_button")
      $stop = $("#stop_button")

      $record.click(function(){
           console.log("record clicked")
           });

      $start.click(function(){
           console.log("start clicked")
           });
   });
```

And the myObject controller is

```
  App.myObject = Ember.Object.create({
      isConditionTrue : false;
  });
```

This sort of works (the buttons are replaced by the text if `myObject.isConditionTrue` is `false`, and appear when `isCondionTrue` is `true`) but when the buttons are displayed, they have no functionality on click. I guess its because they are not in the DOM when didInsertElement is called. So, is there some way to fix this? Should I do child/parent View setup? Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I'm definitely not the guy who can tell what's the right way to do this, because I'm just learning ember too, but here is my working approach on fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/drulia/zkPQt/

Basically every time you switching `myObject.isConditionTrue` to `false`, ember removes your buttons from DOM and that's why your jQuery selectors stops working. I attached ember js {{action}} helper and placed functions responding to the events in myObject, now buttons are working and showing action result on the screen.

Comment: Cool, I think that may work. It will take some refactoring of my application, but it seems to be the right way to go. Will accept if no one can come up with another (easier for me!) solution. Thanks!

Comment: THat worked out,  had to put some things in the controller calls to start(), stop() that should have been in the views really, but all is working.